# Casting issue with maven but not eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, casting, type-safety

I am facing a type casting issue I can't figure out a workaround for.

The context is a legacy project developed in java 6 which has project B depending on project A.
Currently the build process involves generating .class for project A and copy them manually into project B before building it. It is very awkward but it works.

The issue arise when I tried to define the dependencies into the pom so that we can get rid of the manual process and let maven deal with the dependencies.

Here is the code that cause the error:

```
List<RowFilter<MyTableModel, Integer>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<MyTableModel, Integer>>();
myTable.setFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
```

with setFilter defined as:

```
public void setFilter(RowFilter<MyTableModel, Integer> filter)
```

The error I get is:

> setFilter(javax.swing.RowFilter<javax.swing.table.TableModel,java.lang.Integer>)
> cannot be applied to
> (javax.swing.RowFilter<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>)

I need to understand why is it working in the current build process but not when using maven dependencies? And how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: If your code hasn't changed... are you using the same Java version to build? And are your source/target versions the same?

Comment: Yes, nothing changed (same code, same tools, same source/target version).

Comment: What maven version do you use? Maven has a default target of 1.5 (maybe that's also dependent on maven versions).

Comment: It's the eclipse embeded one (version 3.0-SNAPSHOT) and the source and target version are forced to 1.6 in maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: @baadshah Your Eclipse, your Maven and your Java are so old, you shouldn't have been using that for years.

Comment: @howlger thanks for pointing out but that does not help fixing the current issue

Comment: @baadshah Sure? There have been bugs about generics that have been fixed in both Eclipse and `javac` but that have not been backported older releases. What do you get with the current Eclipse and at least Java 8?

Comment: @howlger sorry, i wasn't saying that updating is not solving the issue but rather the fact that just saying it is so old.
As stated, it is a legacy project so it is not as simple as updating everything. It is working as it is, i was just trying to make the process a bit simpler.

Comment: @baadshah Using the current Eclipse which still supports even older Java versions and using Java 8 to compile and run the legacy project should not cause problems and might fix your issue. If it does not fix your issue, workaround that by helping `javac` (which is knowing to have problems with generics with bounds) with a cast: `myTable.setFilter((RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>) RowFilter.andFilter(filters));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229723/discussion-between-baadshah-and-howlger).

Answer (score 0):

After playing a little bit with casts I found the following to work:

1. Do it in each call to setFilter (more than a dozen)

   `myTable.setFilter((RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>) (Object) RowFilter.andFilter(filters));`
2. Or redefine the setFilter signature like this

   `public void setFilter(RowFilter<?, ?> filter)`
3. Or like this

   `public void setFilter(RowFilter filter)`

Can anyone explain why it was not working in the first place and why this is working? Or if there is a better workaround?

In the meantime, i opted for the second option.